# Create a calculated field from q query to another table ms-access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013, calculated-columns

I have table with and ProjectId and more data for instance Name and Quantity.

I have another table with ProjectId, ProjectType and NumberOfthings

How can I created a calculated column that has the summatory of the NumberOfThings values by Project Type and ProjectId ?

For instance getting data by projecttype F in this example I should get in the calculated columns the follow values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to summarize the number of things by ProjectID and ProjectType

SELECT Table1.ProjectID AS ID, Table2.ProjectType AS Type, **Sum(Table2.NumberOfThings) AS Things**
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ProjectID = Table2.ProjectID
**GROUP BY Table1.ProjectID, Table2.ProjectType;**

Results:
ID  Type    Things
1   F   3
2   G   34
3   F   100